# Live USB Linux hibernate/freeze on USB unplug

Tags: linux, hibernate, usb, freeze

I want to replicate a feature that exists on Windows To Go solution into Ubuntu Linux (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592680.aspx#wtg_faq_surprise)

> If the Windows To Go drive is removed, the computer will freeze and the user will have 60 seconds to reinsert the Windows To Go drive. If the Windows To Go drive is reinserted into the same port it was removed from, Windows will resume at the point where the drive was removed. If the USB drive is not reinserted, or is reinserted into a different port, the host computer will turn off after 60 seconds.

This means: I run Linux on an USB Stick, and I want it to freeze if I accidentally unplug the USB. And if I reconnect it, Linux will detect it and return to work. Can anyone point some directions to perform that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing thats going to be more difficult then you think, the linux kernel and other systems need to know to not panic when it happens.  Windows is probably set up better for boot drive failure.

Comment: Maybe if we can make linux changes persist on memory and only write on the disk when shutting down, we can somehow tolerate this. But I'm not sure how can I do that.